# How to make this function not prematurely split?

Tags: c#

I've written this function...

```
internal static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char?, string>> SplitUnescaped(this string input, char[] separators)
{
    int index = 0;
    var state = new Stack<char>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
    {
        char c = input[i];
        char s = state.Count > 0 ? state.Peek() : default(char);

        if (state.Count > 0 && (s == '\\' || (s == '[' && c == ']') || ((s == '"' || s == '\'') && c == s)))
            state.Pop();
        else if (c == '\\' || c == '[' || c == '"' || c == '\'')
            state.Push(c);
        if (state.Count == 0 && separators.Contains(c))
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<char?, string>(c, input.Substring(index, i - index));
            index = i + 1;
        }
    }

    yield return new KeyValuePair<char?, string>(null, input.Substring(index));
}
```

Which splits a string on the given separators, as long as they aren't escaped, in quotes, or in brackets. Seems to work pretty well, but there's one problem with it.

There characters I want to split on include a space:

```
{ '>', '+', '~', ' ' };
```

So, given the string

```
a > b
```

I want it to split on `>` and ignore the spaces, but given

```
a b
```

I *do* want it to split on the space.

How can I fix the function?

Comment: Make some boolean "there was a split on the last character" and don't split if it is setted. That would split `a > b` into `a` and `> b` which is not want you want I guess. But if not, do you want `a > b` to be splitted to `a ` and ` b`? And what about `a> >b`?

Comment: Yes, I want `a > b` to be split into `a` and `b`. `a> >b` is not valid input in my syntax, so I don't really care what happens in that scenario (there can only be one split character between 'parts' with the exception of spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You could continue to split based on   and `>` and then remove the strings which are empty.

Comment: The problem with that is that it needs to return the `>` as part of the `KeyValuePair`, not the space.

Comment: How about removing spaces which appear before and after the other delimiters? a > b becomes a>b and a b stays as a b

Comment: I thought about that, but the problem with that is that spaces in quoted strings like `"a > b"` are significant and shouldn't be removed (or split on).

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it...

```
internal static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char?, string>> SplitUnescaped(this string input, char[] separators)
{
    int startIndex = 0;
    var state = new Stack<char>();
    input = input.Trim(separators);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
    {
        char c = input[i];
        char s = state.Count > 0 ? state.Peek() : default(char);

        if (state.Count > 0 && (s == '\\' || (s == '[' && c == ']') || ((s == '"' || s == '\'') && c == s)))
            state.Pop();
        else if (c == '\\' || c == '[' || c == '"' || c == '\'')
            state.Push(c);
        else if (state.Count == 0 && separators.Contains(c))
        {
            int endIndex = i;
            while (input[i] == ' ' && separators.Contains(input[i + 1])) { ++i; }
            yield return new KeyValuePair<char?, string>(input[i], input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
            while (input[++i] == ' ') { }
            startIndex = i;
        }
    }

    yield return new KeyValuePair<char?, string>(null, input.Substring(startIndex));
}
```

I was trying to push the space onto the stack too before, and then doing some checks against that...but I think this is easier.

Comment: There's a bug in this too... the function will be maintained here http://code.google.com/p/sharp-query/source/browse/trunk/SharpQuery/SharpQuery2/SharpQuery.cs#74 instead... at least for a little while.